k-regular graph has 2k-edge-coloring where each color class has the same size
Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph with $4\ell$ vertices ($k,\ell\geq 1$). Prove or disprove: $G$ has an edge-coloring using $2k$ colors such that each color is used precisely $\ell$ times.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve this problem. This question appeared on the exam of a first-years bachelors course in graph theory, which makes me believe that it should be solvable without advanced theorems.
A simple counting argument shows that $|E(G)| = \frac12\sum_{v\in V(G)}\deg(v) = 2k\ell$, hence it is possible that there is an edge-coloring using $2k$ colors where each color is used $\ell$ times. This aligns with my intuition that the statement should be true. (Or is there a counter-example?)
So far I tried to apply induction on $k$ (and on $|V(G)|$), I tried to find perfect matchings (to decompose the graph), I tried to find Hamiltonian cycles (to decompose the graph), but none has worked...   I would be glad if someone can help me!

I'm considering using Vizing's Theorem. It is not elegant, but i guess it is useful. I'm now working on the case when $\chi'(G)=k+1$. I'll post the answer after I figure it out (if i succeed XD)

I think the answer provided here will help you answer this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334036/equitable-edge-coloring-of-graphs

There is a $2k$-edge coloring by Vizing's theorem, i.e., $\chi'(G) \leq k+1$.
Moreover, there exists a $2k$-edge coloring  $f\colon E(G)\to \{1,\dots,2k\}$ such that for each pair of colors $i,j$ it holds that the difference in size of color class is at most $1$, that is, $$| |f^{-1}(i)| - |f^{-1}(j)| | \leq 1.$$
Namely, suppose there are colors $i$ and $j$ such that $|f^{-1}(i)| > |f^{-1}(j)| + 1$. Let $x=|f^{-1}(i)|$ and $y=|f^{-1}(j)|$.
The subgraph of $G$ consisting of the edges with color $i$ and $j$ contains a path of odd length such that there is one edge of color $i$ more than the number of edges of color $j$.
Now flip the colors on this path, the resulting graph has $x-1$ edges of color $i$ and $y+1$ edges of color $j$.
The sum of squares of sizes of color classes, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^{2k} |f^{-1}(i)|^2$, decreases by at least one, so after finitely many repetitions of this argument the statement holds.
Thus the color classes of the edge coloring $f$ differ by at most $1$ in size. The number of edges of $G$ equals $|E(G)| = 2k\ell$, thus the average size of a color class is $\ell$. Now if one color class has size at least $\ell+1$, then another class has color size at most $\ell-1$ (and vice versa), but two such class differ by at least $2$ in size, so this is not possible. Hence each color class of the edge coloring $f$ has size $\ell$.
